# Emails not being received

Tags: postfix, dovecot, outlook, google

My server was hacked and I've managed to get everything back online and working and hopefully the hole they got in from is plugged, I now have secure passwords in place. Hopefully that was how they got in.

My next problem is that over the course of a couple of days a lot of emails came from my ip. So much so that my ip has been blocked by most receivers. Google wont accept my mail and outlook never did, but now it doesn't even go to spam folders.

I'm trying to start a business. I have the sites back up and running. But I need to be able to send and receive emails. What should I do. Would changing my IP make a difference? Or maybe I should notify Google somehow? What are the next steps to getting my emails received?

**Edit:**

Ok it's been a few days and I've checked on mxtoolbox. The results say everything is fine. The server has no problems. I'm not listed on any blocklists. But I still can't send or receive emails. Only emails from my system to me get through. Server has 451 4.3.5 server configuration errors. Not sure what to do.

**Edit 2:**

I corrected an error with my Sender Policy Framework record.  Outlook and Gmail still will not accept my emails.  I've contacted them though hopefully it won't be to long before they ease the restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

Go on site like mxtoolbox/dnsstuff or similar to check where you are still listed and ask to be delisted.

Most of the time the only recovery possible is to wait a 24/48h period, as when your site will be clean you will be delisted automaticly.

Comment: Great thanks, I was hoping it was something like that. I can wait a few days the important stuff is still running for me. As long as I will get removed in time I'm ok. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You probably got blacklisted on multiple RBL (relay block list).

Quick solution: as RBLs are IP-based, changing your public IP address will immediately solve the issue. However, you had to be **sure** that the server is now safe, otherwise the problem will represent itself shortly.

If you can not change your IP address, follow these steps:

1. go on [anti-abuse](http://www.anti-abuse.org/multi-rbl-check/) and check for your IP address
2. for each RBL that match, you need to ask for de-listing (contacting the RBL admin and/or via a specific mail/form)

Also, consider that some (many?) RBL will auto-delist first-time entries after 24/48 hours.

Comment: Thanks. It is the first time so hopefully they will delist me soon. If not I'll look into the other options. Again thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change IP addresses.
2. Use an external SMTP server to send email - Google Apps, Fastmail, or AuthSMTP are all reputable. Basically bypass sendmail on your server.
3. Set up SPF (Sender Policy Framework)

Comment: I won't change IP just yet. If I don't get delisted soon I'll look into the other options. thanks though.